# Can dd achieve better bandwidth/speeds on a USB 3.0 bus?

Tags: usb, dd

As the title says--I recently acquired a USB 3 stick that I'll mostly be using for moving ISOs/images around between computers. With the increased transfer rate of USB3, can I deviate from my habitual

```
dd if=/dev/foo of=/dev/bar bs=4M
```

now? Would a larger bs parameter break my dd?

Comment: YMMV, but I typically use `bs=1M` - big enough to reduce overhead, but small enough to not propagate stutter from one device to the pipe.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Frankly, I find this question confusing. Just what are you trying to achieve? Why are you copying one device onto another? What do you mean "break" `dd`?

Comment: I'm just curious if I can get through a data transfer faster (using dd) on USB3 than I could on USB2.

Comment: try it and see - it's the only definitive way of knowing in *your* scenario

Answer (score 2):

If the bus is the limiting factor, a faster bus will mean faster data transfer. So it depends on the read speed of the device you are copying from and the write/erase speed of the device you are copying to.